# R - gsub() for to remove dates from data set

Tags: r, regex, substring, gsub

I am using the gsub() function to remove the unwanted text from the data. I just want to have the age in the brackets, not the dates of birth. However, this is in a large data set with differing birth days.

Example of the data:

```
Test1$Age

Sep 10, 1990(27)
Mar 26, 1987(30
Feb 24, 1997(20)
```

Comment: `gsub('\\(([0-9]+)\\)', '\\1', x)`

Comment: Cheers Michael, but this just removes the brackets

Comment: whoops, forgot my `.*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `str_extract()` from the `stringr` package:

```
s <- "Sep 10, 1990(27)"

# get the age in parentheses
stringr::str_extract(s, "\\([0-9]+\\)")

# just the age, with parentheses removed
stringr::str_extract(s, "(?<=\\()[0-9]+")
```

And the output is:

```
> s <- "Sep 10, 1990(27)"
> 
> # get the age in parentheses
> stringr::str_extract(s, "\\([0-9]+\\)")
[1] "(27)"
> 
> # just the age, with parentheses removed
> stringr::str_extract(s, "(?<=\\()[0-9]+")
[1] "27"
```

The first regular expression matches paired parentheses containing one or more digits. The second regular expression uses [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match one or more digits following an opening parenthesis.

If your data is in a data.frame `df` with the column named `age`, then you could do the following:

```
df$age <- stringr::str_extract(df$age, "\\([0-9]+\\)")
```

Or, in `tidyverse` notation:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(age = stringr::str_extract(age, "\\([0-9]+\\)"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two problems:

1. the date prior to the left parenthesis is not wanted
2. the right parenthesis is sometimes missing and it needs to be inserted

**1) sub** These can be addressed with `sub`.  Match

- any number of characters `.*` followed by
- a literal left parenthesis `[(]` followed by
- digits in a capture group `(\\d+)` followed by
- an optional right parenthesis `[)]?`

and then replace that with a left parenthesis, the match to the capture group `\\1` and a right parenthesis.

No packages are used.

```
pat <- ".*[(](\\d+)[)]?"
transform(test, Age = sub(pat, "(\\1)", Age))
```

If, instead, you wanted the age as a numeric field then:

```
transform(test, Age = as.numeric(sub(pat, "\\1", Age)))
```

**2) substring/sub**  Another possibility is to take the 13th character onwards which gives everything from the left parenthesis to the end of the string and insert a ) if missing.  `)?$` matches a right parenthesis at the end of the string or just the end of the string if none.  That is replaced with a right parenthesis.  Again, no packages are used.

```
transform(test, Age = sub(")?$", ")", substring(Age, 13))
```

A variation of this if we wanted a numeric Age instead would be to take everything from the 14th character and remove the final ) if present.

```
transform(test, Age = as.numeric(sub(")", "", substring(Age, 14))))
```

**3) read.table**  Use `read.table` to read the `Age` field with `sep = "("` and `comment.char = ")"` and pick off the second column read.  This will give the numeric age and we can use `sprintf` to surround that with parentheses.  If `Age` were character (as opposed to factor) then `as.character(Age)` could optionally be written as just `Age`.

Again, no packages are used.  This one does not use regular expressions.

```
transform(test, Age = 
  sprintf("(%s)", read.table(text = as.character(Age), sep = "(", comment.char = ")")$V2)
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
test <- data.frame(Age = c("Sep 10, 1990(27)", "Mar 26, 1987(30", "Feb 24, 1997(20)"))
```